# Get value of selected dropdown option

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the value of a selected option with this Jquery function.

Thanks for any help.

```js
$("#getlogo select").change(function(){
$('.active-logo').text(this.checked ? $(this).val() : ''); 
$("#logo").css("background-image", this.checked ? this.dataset.image : 'none');
}).change();
```

```html
<div class="confi" id="logo"></div>


<div class="second-title" href="#getlogo">
<span class="active-logo"></span>
</div>                      
         
<div class="radio-toolbar" id="getlogo">
   
<select name="contact[Logoanbringung]">
<option data-image="url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0600/1373/files/black.jpg?7641506985692805254)" id="ohne_logo" value="Ohne Logo">Ohne Logo</option>
<option data-image="url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0600/1373/files/white.jpg?17364807047771987067)" id="heissfolienpraegung" value="Heißfolienprägung">Heißfolienprägung</option>
<option data-image="url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0600/1373/files/chamois.jpg?17364807047771987067)" id="blindpraegung" value="Blindprägung">Blindprägung</option>
</select>  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a question here? `this` is the `<select>` not an `<option>`

Comment: the code snippet you provide here is completely different from your question of what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do this as-

```
$('select').change(function(){
  $(this).val();
});
```

or what I am guessing here is that you want to get `data-image`

```
$('select').change(function(){
   var selectedImage=  $('option:selected',this).data('image');
  });
```